# Log props passed with component name in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When a specific url loads my react app I would like to log the props passed to each component on that page. I would like to know the name of the component( it’s name just or the specific file name) and the props it has received

I would like to log it in a file when I run app on local or just console log

Right now I have to go to each component and make a console.log of the props which is difficult as we have a huge react app with huge levels of components

Comment: You can probably use [`React.Children.forEach`](https://www.reactenlightenment.com/basic-react-components/6.8.html) to iterate over each child and log it's props. You would need that function to live in the topmost parent and then iterate through all of the children.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda is there a base react component prebuilt in react through which each component is loaded, then that would be the place I would like to log

Comment: @Zuz C No, but if you put the code in your main `App` component it should work the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing context of which you require this, my main suggestion would be to use the React dev tools to inspect the components.

The tools are available in both [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi) and [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/react-devtools/).

I find these tools really helpful when wanting to see the state or props used within the component hierarchy. Worth noting you can also use the tools to edit the state and props.

Comment: Devtools would require me to manually inspect each component to check props passed to it, for each and every component on each and every page that is too much